# Filebeat Central Management Alternative

Tags: configuration, elastic-stack, filebeat, central

We have a on-premise setup of the free version of the ELK stack. Actually Elasticsearch cluster and some Kibana nodes (no Logstash).
On the application servers we have installed filebeat 7.9.0 which ships the logs to the Elasticsearch ingest nodes, and there is very minimal processing done by the filebeat on the log events before sending (e.g. multiline=true, dissect, drop_fields and json_decode).

As of today, there are only 3 application servers on the production set-up, but it might scale to more number of machines (application servers) going forward.

I understand that, the central management of the filebeat configuration is possible (which is also coming to its end of life) with a license version of ELK stack.

I want to know what are the alternatives available to manage the filebeat configuration apart from the central management through Kibana.

The goal is in future if number of application servers grow to lets say 20, and the filebeat configuration has to undergo a change, changing the configuration on each of the servers shall be manual activity with its own risks associated. i.e. change the configuration at one location and somehow it is updated on filebeat on all application servers.

Please let me know, if this can be achieved ..
Any pointers / thoughts towards the solution let me know

Note: We do not have infrastructure as a code in the organization yet, so this may not be a suitable solution.

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

The replacement of Central Management is Elastic Fleet: Installing a single agent on a server, the rest can be done from Kibana. https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-elastic-agent-and-ingest-manager gives a better overview of the features and current screenshots.

Most parts of Fleet are also available for free.